# Xamarin Android: Binding socket error (Machine is not on the network)

Tags: c#, android, sockets, xamarin

**Error** Java.Net.SocketException: Binding socket to network 626 failed: ENONET (Machine is not on the network)

Xamarin app: this method is written for android.

I am getting this error, it is not reported every time, it is difficult for me to capture it in test environments.

**Why is this error, what is the explanation?**
**what can be done to have better control in this method?**

There is a similar question asked some time ago, but it does not the same operation that I do here, and it is not solved.

```
public static void BindSocketToWifi(Socket socket)
            {
                try
                {
    
                        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
                        NetworkInfo wifiInfo = null;
    
                        var networks = connectivityManager.GetAllNetworks();
                        foreach (var net in networks)
                        {
                            wifiInfo = connectivityManager.GetNetworkInfo(net);
                            if (wifiInfo.Type == ConnectivityType.Wifi)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    net.BindSocket((Socket)socket);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                                    throw ex;
                                }
    
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Crashes.TrackError(e);
                    throw e;
                }
            }
```

Comment: read the title: Binding socket to network 626 failed: ENONET (Machine is not on the network)

Comment: more clear for you?